senses of independent harmonic polynomials Laplacian
By harmonic here i mean solutions to Laplacian, Laplaces equation=$0,\,\sum_{i=1}^{d} d^2\;(...)^n/dxi^2 =0, or\, say\,\; \Delta(...)^n=0$ for d dimensions and $(...)^n$ a homogenous total degree n polynomial when after expanded and using rectangular coord's all numbers will be cst's and exponents non neg integers. Want to find relate the total number of independents to solutions of
$\Delta((a1+ib1)x1+(a2+ib2)x2+...+(ad+ibd)xd)^n=0$ where here $i$ means $\sqrt{-1}$ and d is number of dimensions and for now use simple rectangular coordinates. And take real and imaginary parts of $(...)^n$ which i will assume are independent for $d>2$ ? So this also means $\sum_{j=1}^{d}(aj+ibj)^2=0$ which implies $\sum_{j=1}^d(aj\,bj)=0$ and $\sum_j(aj^2-bj^2)=0$. Using the college/highschool taught that in solutions to $\sum_i ci(expression\;i)=0$. Where the $ci$ restricted to cst's , that they are independent if only solution is for all $ci's=0$. Now I am going to revise that expression so that the condition is changed so that rhs=cst rather than zero which is the way it should have been written in the first place. Anyway I may at first blatantly(unfortunately wrong) assume this means have $\binom{n+d-1}{n}$ independents and have 2 or 3 conditions that must be satisfied so taking real/imag. parts get $2\binom{n+d-1}{n}-2$ independents for $d>4$ which is wrong and also wrong if replaced the -2 by -3. For one the conditions are not linear and this multiplying by 2 for real/imag. parts is not correct either. Actually now that i think about it should have used 3 conditions $\sum_i^d ai^2=1$ , $\sum_{j=1}^d(aj\,bj)=0$ and $\sum_j(aj^2-bj^2)=0$ on $2d$ possibilities being the real and imaginary parts $ai,bi$. Though where to go from there in figuring the total number of independent possibilities i am not sure.
So does anyone know how to get the correct answer along these lines and making the conditions linear real expressions ? In the textbook Quantum Mechanics by Kramers H.A. he essentially does this but only for 3 dimensions and it is rather complicated and lengthy, and still not sure would consider all his conditions as linear, but anyway in time I was able to reconcile his derivation.
Now doing it a different way which seems much simpler to find the total number of independent polynomials I can and do understand another authors textbook derivation which i paste here.
I understand it without his proof clause. Especially his statement $\Delta[||x||^2\,P(x)]\neq 0$. Does anyone know why and where he is getting that as i see nowhere he has used that or proven that condition at all nor of what relevance that is to his proof !
Anyway that is not such a big deal as it is understandable without that clause. But follows is the real 'clicker,kicker' which I paste.

NOw this is my main question and problem. My only concern is not with the gist of his derivations as i basically can follow those. But it is the very last line where he writes the figures $\binom{n+d-2}{d-2}+\binom{n+d-3}{d-2}$. Yea it gives the correct answer as derived above in his passage Definition 4.1.1. But I see nowhere does this follow from any of his proposition 4.1.3 and all that follows under that. Scratch that last remark as i now see from where it originates.

Can you say precisely from which textbook and which pages the screenshots are taken?

'Orthogonal Polynomials of several variables'  a book by Charles_F._Dunkl,_Yuan_Xu and these scans were from pages 115 and 116

to my surprise i  was  able , see answer , to see the connection of that last part of the question as to where he got those binomial expressions.

Under condition i may be able to find an explanation to that last part of where does he get the two numbers in $\binom{n+d-2}{d-2}+\binom{n+d-3}{d-2}$ which is equivalent $\binom{n+d-2}{n}+\binom{n+d-3}{n-1}$ and in this form it is much easier to decipher. First he writes above that $n_d$ must equal 0 or 1 in the manner of his proof convention which I can sort of justify though not as well as i should. So anyway assuming this and now here is the big if and that is whether or not $n_d$ counts in the requirement that $\sum_{i=1}^d n_i=n$ for homogenous polynomial total degree n or do we neglect $n_d$ in that sum ?
In any case we have the sum of the two cases $n_d\!=\!0\,or\,1$ to consider as possibilities. If assume that $n_d$ DOES count in the sum then if it is $0$ it is the same as considering $d\!-\!1$ dimensions or say variables with total sum n which gives $\binom{n+d-2}{n}$ possibilities plus the  possibilities for the second case that $n_d=1$ and again $d\!-\!1$ variables whose non neg integer powers of each totals $n\!-\!1$ which is $\binom{n-1+d-2}{n-1}$ possibilities. So in that case it does give the correct answer for each of the two binomial numbers being what they are since it exactly agrees. So seems he is assuming that $n_d$ does count in the sum of powers or exponents of each of the d variables in all the product d variables possibilities and requiring that each must be a non negative integer. So it comes down to why is he counting $n_d$ in that sum and or why it should or should it not be counted ? Ok now scratch that last remark as i now see the reason it should be counted and why $n_d$ is restricted to 0,1 . That is in his remark in Proposition 4.1.3 '...assume g(...xd) is harmonic..." and $x^{nd}$ is only harmonic if $nd=0,1$. Prior i did not take particular note of that remark/text in his proposition.
